# Bootstrap 4 form select cuts off in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Every select form that I have on my site cuts off in Firefox. Tested in Firefox 55.0.3 for Mac (64 bit) and Windows (32 bit) with the same results.

Using Bootstrap 4 beta

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="genre">Genre</label>
   <select name="genre" id="genre" class="form-control">
       @foreach ($genres as $genre)
          <option value="{{ $genre->id}}" {{ $selected }}>{{ $genre->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

I've been searching the web for solutions but didn't see anybody addressing this specific problem.

Comment: totallly a `line-height` issue, but without seeing the declared styles, no way of knowing

Comment: @albert the only styles I have right now is bootstrap 4 css framework. I don't have any personal style sheets at this time.

Comment: Can you provide your head tag?

Comment: @MasterZ i figured that from the post...unfortunately most people don't have that entire style sheet memorized. since you want help, you should post it, because some people (like me) aren't going to go find what you are using to help you.

Comment: @albert Ah, okay. Sorry about that. I thought it was too much to post, then remembered Pastebin when itodd asked for it. :)

Comment: all good man. i saw what you did below. thanks! pastebin's a good option. or even just linking to it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide your CSS that you are applying to this select and .form-control

Trying adding this to your CSS

```
.form-control {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: I added that to my css and it didn't change the result, even when I put in a ridiculous height option.

Comment: Can you post the css you are using? It may be something else is overriding these styles

Comment: I have updated my answer, try adding that to the end of your CSS

Comment: you, sir, are awesome. Thank you :)